# Cannot run image portainer/portainer with slash in image name

Tags: docker

According to the docs the `--restart on-failure` parameter to `docker run` should ensure the container runs even if it fails or, as we would like it, after a reboot.

### What is wrong with this command?

```
docker run -d --restart on-failure -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /data/portainer:/data portainer/portainer --name portainer
```

When I run this I get the following from `docker container ls`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                                            NAMES
84660367b574        portainer/portainer   "/portainer --name p…"   2 seconds ago       Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp   mystifying_shtern
```

The image is OK, as are the ports but the command is wrong/garbled and the name is ignored.

I have tried placing the image name `portainer/portainer` in quotes and at the end of the command to no avail. It looks like docker just isn't parsing the command line correctly.

Comment: pass `--name` before container

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
docker run -d --restart on-failure -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /data/portainer:/data --name portainer portainer/portainer
```

Arguments after your image name are passed as arguments to your container entrypoint.